# Trying to make tags look consitent in a tag cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I am trying to achieve this: http://prntscr.com/2zurxz But so far able to do this: http://prntscr.com/2zus2j

Any CSS, Javascript expert out there to help?

HTML/CSS code is there: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qau2g/)

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block tags">
    <a href="#">sportcards</a>
    <a href="#">atari</a>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    width: 208px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
}

.tags {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: none;
}

.tags a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #107ea1;
    background: #e0f4fb;
    padding: 7px 13px 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.tags a:hover {
    background: #9bdaee;
}
```

Comment: Any HTML, CSS &/or JS?

Comment: Where and How can I post code here?

Comment: @MrQj edit your question. Paste it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To fit them perfectly you will need javascript.

Take a look at [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

### Edit:

That link doesn't load examples for some reason.. try [this](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/)

Comment: tried but not worked as desired. almost same look as i had using css.